# native_get_picture: MSM_CAM_IOCTL_GET_PICTURE fd 21 error Bad address

Tags: java, android, camera

I have an issue with a simple app that takes a picture and tweets it. The app works in the debugger and on a Galaxy S3 running CM10.2, but it fails on an LG GW620 running CM7.2. The built-in camera app does work on the LG.

The error message is:

> 09-12 20:43:49.031: E/QualcommCameraHardware(1323): native_get_picture: MSM_CAM_IOCTL_GET_PICTURE fd 21 error Bad address
>   09-12 20:43:49.031: E/QualcommCameraHardware(1323): getPicture failed!

And the code looks like this:

```
    // take the picture
    _cam = Camera.open()
    Log.d(TAG, "Taking picture...");
    _cam.setPreviewCallback(null); // work around that doesn't work
    _cam.setOneShotPreviewCallback(null); // work around that doesn't work
    _cam.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
    Log.d(TAG, "Picture taken.");
```

None of the callbacks are being called on the LG phone while on emulator and Galaxy they all are.

My question: what does the "fd 21 Bad address" mean? (I'm guessing the camera can't write memory because it is being pointed to an address it doesn't have access to. But how can I even influence that at all?)